# How to write a procedure to modify the elements and size of a dynamic array without knowing the size?

Tags: c++

The following is a question from an exam in programming I had recently. Neither me nor the other students have found a way of solving it. The professor says it is possible, however refused to tell us what the solution is. The question:

Write a procedure with a header of:

```
void ArrayUpdate( int ??? array, int ??? delAmount, int ??? addAmout)
```

- The procedure is used to modify elements of a dynamic array passed through the first argument.
- The procedure should remove the *delAmount* of the first cells from the array. It should also add *addAmount* of elements to the back of the array with whole numbers read from std::cin.
- The "???" need to be replaced or removed.
- Square brackets "[ ]" can only be used with **new** or **delete**.
- Only **iostream** and **fstream** may be included. (fstream was needed for another question, so it may not be needed here.)

Comment: Tell your professor to stop it and start using `std::vector`.  The code would never pass code review in a modern code base.

Comment: remove all parameters and pass iterators instead. I dont get what this exercise is aiming at other than keeping you away from writing c++

Comment: That is you can replace "???" with whatever you want except []??

Comment: Well, this is another teacher that will contribute to this set of students dropping C++ and taking up (and liking) Java or Python.

Comment: What if my `<iostream>` includes all of `std`? Seems like a silly limitation to impose.

Comment: Not using `operator[]` doesn't prevent you from using good old pointer arithmetic to access elements anyway. Sounds like another silly requirement.

Comment: Well if ??? can be freely replaced then what about: "int *& array", you can reassign argument passed to ArrayUpdate, this way you can delete it and reallocate, .... What do you think?

Comment: Calm down guys, he obviously just wants them to research pointer arithmetic. And it seems like it is working well. You don't really understand the code if you just use pre-defined methods without exploring what goes on behind them.

Comment: Take a page from good ol' Pascal. Store the size of the array in the first array element. Since the array is resizable store the capacity in the second or something like that.

Comment: Honestly, this is a waste-of-time exercise.  Why the riddles?  Just teach pointer manipulation (if that's the goal) without the foolishness of "???".

Comment: .... but still,  ArrayUpdate must know the size of the array to update it - preserving old data

Comment: @marcinj you are correct. Maybe its a combination of `void ArrayUpdate( int *& array, int delAmount, int addAmout)` and storing size and capacity in the first two elements.

Comment: Step 1: choose `int *, int, int` / Step 2: assume that `<iostream>` includes `<vector>` on your implementation / Step 3: require that the user call the function with `reinterpret_cast<int*>(&someVector)` / Step 4: perform the opposite cast / Step 5: business as usual ;)

Comment: @IFunball no, because `array` is an `int *`, not an array, and that formula would just give you `1`.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, you're right. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

- ***"The procedure is used to modify elements of a dynamic array passed through the first argument."*** It does not say how the array is organized. The first element, as @user4581301 suggested, might be the size of the array. In other words, the first element of the array is at **position 1, not 0**. This is most likely what your teacher had in mind. The purpose is to teach you pointers/references and the array layout.
- **Creating** an array:

  ```
  void CreateArray( int*& array, int size )
  {
    array = new int[ size + 1 ];
    array[ 0 ] = size;
  }
  ```

  You may use `int**` instead of `int*&`, but it is harder to write/read.
- Retrieving the **size**:

  ```
  int ArraySize( int* array )
  {
    return *array;
  }
  ```
- **Usage**:

  ```
  int* array;
  CreateArray( array, 10 );
  //...
  for ( int i = 1; i <= ArraySize(array); ++i )
    // ...
  ```
- Function **signature**:

  ```
  void ArrayUpdate( int*& array, int delAmount, int addAmout);
  ```

Comment: This has the downside of forcing origin 1 indexing onto the programmer and that could lead to many hilarious bugs. Nothing prevents you from lying and setting `array = temp_allocation[1];` Why the hell am I commenting and not answering? I really suck at this answering thing.

Comment: @user4581301 Right, but I am assuming the task is not about real world.

Comment: The array size function is a great addition. That's worth an upvote by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my hack-cut at the problem. It's very similar to ZDF's, but it adds the array's `capacity` to the book-keeping and lies and hides the book-keeping by giving the caller a pointer to the middle of the array rather than the beginning. This allows the user to use the array as a regular array, but will crash if they try to `delete` it themselves.

Comments embedded where I figured more explanation was required.

```
//Magic numbers are evil.
constexpr int bookkeeping = 2;
constexpr int sizeOff = -2;
constexpr int capOff = -1;

void ArrayUpdate( int *& array, int delAmount, int addAmount)
{
    int size;
    int capacity;

    // can't do jack with a non-existent array, so let's make sure we have one.
    if (array != nullptr)
    {
        size = *(array + sizeOff);
        capacity = *(array + capOff);
    }
    else
    {
        size = 0;
        capacity = 0;
    }
    if (delAmount > size) // can't delete more than we have.
    {
        delAmount = size; 
        // alternative: freak out here. Abort, throw exception, whatever
    }
    int * to; // track where data goes to
    int * temp; // location of new buffer, if resized
    bool resized;
    int newsize =size + addAmount - delAmount;
    if (newsize > capacity)
    { 
        capacity *=2;
        if (capacity < newsize)
        {
            capacity = newsize;
        }
        temp = new int[capacity+bookkeeping];
        to = temp + bookkeeping; // point to where we want data to go:
                                 // after the book-keeping.
        resized = true;
    }
    else
    {
        to = array;
        resized = false;
    }
    // use std::copy or memcpy here, but since we're not allowed the appropriate
    // headers, here comes ol' brute force!
    if (delAmount || resized) // need to copy old data around
    { 
        for (int index = delAmount; index < size; index++)
        {
            *to++ = *(array + index);
        }
    }
    // add new data
    for (int count = 0; count < addAmount; count++)
    {
        if (std::cin >> *to) // always test to make sure you got good input
        {
            to++;
        }
        else
        { // Bad input. Clean up
            std::cin.clear();

            // normally I'd use cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')
            // here to kill all the remaining user input, but no <limits>
            std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            // might also want to just read and discard until you find the
            // first whitespace. That's can be done easily by >> to a std::string,
            // but no string header allowed. 
        }
    }

    if (resized)
    {
        if (array != nullptr) // normally deleting nullptr is safe, but not when
                              // you're going to modify it with an offset
        {
            delete[] (array - bookkeeping);
        }
        array = temp + bookkeeping; // array hides the extra book-keeping
        *(array + capOff) = capacity;
    }
    if (array != nullptr)
    {
        *(array + sizeOff) = newsize;
    }
}
```

Not exhaustively tested. May be a bug or two in there.

For completeness, here's test code and a Free Array routine:

```
void FreeArray(int * array)
{
    delete[] (array - bookkeeping);
}

void printarray(const int * array)
{
    int size;
    int capacity;
    if (array != nullptr)
    {
        size = *(array + sizeOff);
        capacity = *(array + capOff);
    }
    else
    {
        size = 0;
        capacity = 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Size: " << size <<"\nCapacity: "<< capacity << '\n';
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        std::cout << array[index] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int * array = nullptr;
    printarray(array);
    ArrayUpdate(array, 5, 0);
    printarray(array);
    ArrayUpdate(array, 5, 5);
    printarray(array);
    ArrayUpdate(array, 5, 5);
    printarray(array);
    ArrayUpdate(array, 0, 5);
    printarray(array);
    ArrayUpdate(array, 5, 0);
    printarray(array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If "???" can be replaced by whatever you want, so you can pass to your function a pointer to an int, or a pointer to pointer to int, etc...

So the trick in C++ when dealing with memory management, or range, is to store 2 pointers one to the begin of the array and one to its end:

```
//a range:
int* limits[2];
int ** array = limits;
```

Then if you change the size of the range inside a function you must pass it by reference:

```
void ArrayUpdate( int ** array, int delAmount, int addAmout){
   int* begin = array[0];
   int* end = array[1];
   //end so on
   }
```

Comment: @Quentin a yes it can be simpler, but not with that constraints in the question (it is not possible to declare int(& array)[2]

Comment: @Quentin but i think I have said to much, this is a home work, used to make student learn.

Comment: The range array has absolutely no reason to be on the free store: you do not need to reallocate it ;)

Comment: I'm still puzzled by your insistence on using `int**&` -- red herrings?

Comment: @Quentin no, just red wine.